# Extracting small numpy array from a bigger raster, by moving windows. Memory issues. ArcGIS

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-10.2, numpy

I'm trying to extract a small raster from a bigger one, just using python and numpy (I'm not allow to use any other software). This code just reads a from a big raster, extracts an smaller window, convert it to numpy array, convert it back to raster format and then save the small raster (Stepping stone to add more complexity later).  [RasterToNumpyArray](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q300000029000000) seems to work fine, because I'm able to extract just a small patch from a bigger raster (8G+). So I'm running two nested loops in order to create the moving window. The running windows sweeps the source raster in (5 x 3, columns x rows). The code runs fine with the first inner loop. It generates two small rasters perfectly, but by the next rows run, I've got memory issues (type exceptions.MemoryError)

My thought is that [RasterToNumpyArray](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q300000029000000) doesn't loads all the raster in memory (and I don't think it does, otherwise It couln't load an 8G raster into 2G ram).
My question is: what is causing the memory issues? How to solve them?

Some specs: Using ArcGIS 10.2, Operating system Microsoft Windows 7 16bit, 16G RAM, I don't know about SWAP RAM.

ps: When using [DefineProjection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000077000000) in an empty raster (or more precisely: in a raster with all its cells *null*), throws an error. That's why I  used try/except within the nested loops.

This is a portion of the code:

```
  for rows in range (0,4):
      for columns in range (0,5):
          arcpy.AddMessage('> Attempt to extract raster [row]-[col]: [' + str(rows)+ ']-['+str(columns)+']...')
          try:
              small_raster_lower_left  = arcpy.Point(large_raster_extent.XMin + (columns * window_size * large_raster_cellsize_X),
                                                     large_raster_extent.YMin + (rows    * window_size * large_raster_cellsize_Y)
                                                     )


              arcpy.AddMessage('> Raster to Numpy...')
              numpy_array  = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(large_raster,
                                            small_raster_lower_left,
                                            window_size,
                                            window_size,
                                            nodata_to_value=-99999
                                            )

              arcpy.AddMessage('> small raster coordinates. X: {0}, Y: {1}'.format(small_raster_lower_left.X,small_raster_lower_left.Y))

              arcpy.AddMessage('> Numpy to raster...')
              small_raster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(numpy_array,            
                                      small_raster_lower_left,
                                      large_raster_cellsize_X,
                                      large_raster_cellsize_Y,
                                      value_to_nodata = -99999
                                      )

              arcpy.DefineProjection_management(small_raster, large_raster_spatial_ref)
              small_raster_name = "small_dem_" + str(columns+rows*10)
              arcpy.AddMessage('> Success! Saving raster: ' + small_raster_name + '...')  
              small_raster.save(small_raster_name)
              del numpy_array
              del small_raster


         except:
              arcpy.AddMessage('> Fault! Trying next window...')
              del numpy_array
              del small_raster
```

[image: Two small rasters succesfully extracted form a bigger one, in color.]

Comment: Please edit the question to specify the version of ArcGIS in use, along with the operating system, and physical RAM and virtual RAM (swap) configured on the platform.

Comment: Done. And If I check the System Monitor, while running code and saving the small rasters the RAM goes up to 850 +/- , but after the code starts doing the 'empty'/'faulty' rasters it seems to pile them up and very quick passes the 2K RAM use and stuck there.

Comment: What's Windows 360?  It's not an operating system.  Do you mean 2Gb RAM, not 2K?

Comment: That was the office suite! :P  OS: Windows 7 - 64bit, installed RAM 16GB, available 15.9. Regarding the RAM, in system performance, processes tab, says Memory (Private Working Set) 2,110,740K for ArcMap. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to specify the OS.  Whenever there are memory issues (and in general, as best practice), you should always explicitly delete (`del`) large objects instead of allowing Python to remove them when unreferenced.  This can help prevent hyper-inefficient heap utilization, where blocks of memory aren't made available until after more space is used, and the "collected" space isn't large enough for the next requested block, so even more space is used, fragmenting the heap until no space is available. You should also consider trying the 64-bit background processing module.

Comment: @Vince,   I've follow the advice on using del . Even thougth the code generates more rasters than before, is still building up unused memory allocated. Any other ways to free memory? where this alocations of RAM commes from? Thanks.

Comment: Be sure to install Desktop Background Geoprocessing 64-bit and enable it. This can fix a lot of problems when working with larger datasets.

Comment: I'll do @klewis , but this didn't actually get rid of the problem... Do you know why that happens? Is something wrong in the way of coding, of is just how python manages memory/objects?

Comment: Try removing the AddMessage statements inside the loop.  I bet they're fragmenting your heap by adding small objects in between the large ones.

Answer (score 1):

If your Arc license includes spatial analyst you could just use '[extract by rectangle](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/extract-by-rectangle.htm)' with a couple of iterators set up to re-define the extent object for each new extraction window. Without SA, '[Data management - clip](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/clip.htm)' should be able to be used in a similar way.